# binding exists property in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, mxml

how can i do binding exists property in actionscript e.g. i want image still in middle aplication..in mxml i do this simple as `<mx:Image source="image.jpg" x="{this.width/2}"`/> ...i don't know how can i do this simple in actionscript without event handlers... i put this code to application_creationCompleteHandler..
something like `var image:Image = new Image(); image.source="image.jpg"; image.x=this.width/2;` or have i put this to another function?? i can't do e.g. updateComplete event handler and change it there...

thanks
pavel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the BindingUtils class and its bindSetter method. You can bind a setter to the "width" property and adjust the x property of your image in that handler.

Comment: +1 or the right answer.  I can't help w/ accepting the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that as3 is OO language i always start from something like this:

```
    public class App extends Sprite { 

        public function App() { //constructor   
            super();    //extends class constructor     
            loading();  //your function were you set all elements properties
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the context of Flex, I would not recommend this approach.  Making use of the Flex Component LifeCycle is a much better approach.  Create your children, and set their properties, in createChildren().  coordinate property changes in commitProperties(); and update visual elements in updateDisplayList().

Comment: probably as Flash developer and NOT Flex i shouldn't try to answer such specifically flex questions.